# textfield frame origin change when keyboard shows

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, position, landscape-portrait

i'm trying change the textfield frame origin when the device is in landscape.

In my login view the pass textfield it's below user textfield (Portrait),
when change the orientation (Landscape) the user textfield it's to the left of pass textfield.

```
override func willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval) {
        if(toInterfaceOrientation.isLandscape){                 
            labelPass.frame.origin.x = buttonEnter.frame.midX+5
            textfieldPass.frame.origin.x = buttonEnter.frame.midX+5

            labelUser.frame.origin.x = buttonEnter.frame.midX-textfieldUser.frame.width-5
            textfieldUser.frame.origin.x = buttonEnter.frame.midX-textfieldUser.frame.width-5

            labelUser.frame.origin.y = labelPass.frame.origin.y
            textfieldUser.frame.origin.y = textfieldPass.frame.origin.y
        }
    }
```

In iPhone 4 all it´s ok, but in iPhone 5 version 8.4 (in landscape) when the keyboard is shown the textfields lose their position and return (pass textfield below user textfield). In the Storyboard wAny hAny pass textfield it's below user textfield.

I tested this

```
func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
    if(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape){
        labelPass.frame.origin.x = buttonEnter.frame.midX+5
        textfieldPass.frame.origin.x = buttonEnter.frame.midX+5

        labelUser.frame.origin.x = buttonEnter.frame.midX-textfieldUser.frame.width-5
        textfieldUser.frame.origin.x = buttonEnter.frame.midX-textfieldUser.frame.width-5

        labelUser.frame.origin.y = labelPass.frame.origin.y
        textfieldUser.frame.origin.y = textfieldPass.frame.origin.y        
    }
 }
```

With the same result.

Any idea?, thank you very much to all

Comment: try autolayout for this effect instead in codes. Research about size classes

Comment: What stops you from using a scroll view (or even a table view) including the text fields?

Comment: I do not need to move up the textfield because the keyboard hide them . I need to change the position of the textfield below one another textfield .

to a TextField to the right of another textfield. Thanks!!!